# how to change the height of the textLabel of UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to set this font to the text label. Font is setting correctly.But it is hiding (Please see the screenshot).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Text Color
   UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    header.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Damascus" size:13];
}
```

[image]

```
 - (nullable NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return @"faq";
 }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   NSLog(@"Coming here");
  return 50;
  }
```

Comment: where is the screen shot

Comment: No @RealmOfFire

Comment: Please check the edited code.

Comment: i suugest you set your headerview as customcell

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian i think my way is easier ...

Comment: ok you know about customcell?

Comment: You mean UITableViewCell right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168211/discussion-between-realmoffire-and-saranya-subramanian).

Comment: I got it what ever we ll do for making custom table row the same thing we need to do for custom table header view right ????if i am wrong correct me

Comment: No - don't use a cell for the header or footer, just a regular `UIView`.

Comment: try this - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
to adjust footer height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Damascus" size: 10.0f]];
[yourSuperView addSubview:yourLabel];
```

Comment: how to hide the default text label?

Comment: Just set your textLabel with your new text

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *tableviewHeader = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourcustomcellname" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return tableviewHeader;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RealmOFire. I have one more doubt.For custom table view cell,  we ll create subclass of UITableViewCell,For TableHeader Custom cell what ll be the class

Comment: only create xib and set that file owner to viewcontroller(where you want use header)  file

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian your class should be your view controller where you use header got it.

Comment: I didn't get, Can you please explain the step in detail ? Because I am very new to ios

Comment: Create a `UIView` with a `UILabel` to show your text inside it. Then set your headerView to be this `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, view.frame.size.width-20, 60)];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
NSString *string =@"FAQ//....your label text";
[label setText:string];
label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
label.numberOfLines=0;
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[view addSubview:label];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];//set which color you want
return view;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 60;
}
```

> hope it help's-:)